# reference quest: surface whose $1$-forms have a common zero

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

What are classical/simple examples of smooth projective surfaces $S$ (over $\mathbb C$) for which all the $1$-forms have a common zero (and $h^{1,0}(S)>0$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S$ admits a global holomorphic 1-form without zeros, $S$ would admit a $C^\infty$ real closed 1-form which has no zeros, equivalently, $S$ would admit a $C^\infty$ fibre bundle structure over the circle.

In this way, the Euler number $\chi(S)$ and the signature $\sigma (S)$ vanish: see [Holomorphic one-forms, fibrations over the circle, and characteristic numbers of Kähler manifolds](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/holomorphic-oneforms-fibrations-over-the-circle-and-characteristic-numbers-of-kahler-manifolds/DAC4529082DBF6F70474970ACFA70426), Lemma 2.

So a simple choice may be a surface with either $\chi(S)$ or $\sigma (S)$  non-vanishing, and  $h^{1,0}(S)=1$. A concrete example may be the [Cartwright-Steger surface](https://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/donaldc/cs-surface/cs-surface.pdf). See also [Enumeration of the 50 fake projective planes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1631073X09003987).

Answer (score 5):

If $S$ is any surface with $h^{1,0}(S) = 1$, then the Albanese morphism is a surjection $a \colon S \to E$ to an elliptic curve, and the pullback $H^0(E,\Omega_E^1) \to H^0(S,\Omega_S^1)$ is an isomorphism (see for instance [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/368825/82179)). So the only question is whether the pullback $a^* \omega$ of a nontrivial $1$-form $\omega$ on $E$ has a zero somewhere.

If $a$ is not smooth, then the pullback $a^* \omega$ vanishes at any singular point $s \in S$ for $a$. Indeed, note that $a$ is singular at $s$ if and only if $\dim_{\kappa(s)}\bigl(\Omega^1_{S/E} \otimes \kappa(s)\bigr) > 1$, which means that the pullback $a^* \colon \Omega^1_E\otimes \kappa(a(s)) \to \Omega^1_S \otimes \kappa(s)$ is the zero map (since $\dim_{\kappa(s)} \Omega_S^1 \otimes \kappa(s) = 2$).

So any surface whose Albanese morphism is a surjection $a \colon S \to E$ with at least one singular fibre gives a counterexample. For instance, if $S$ is a surface of general type with $h^{1,0}(S) = 1$ (in this case, the vanishing of its global $1$-form also follows from [PS14]).

---

**References.**

[PS14]  M. Popa, C. Schnell, [*Kodaira dimension and zeros of holomorphic one-forms*](https://doi.org/10.4007/annals.2014.179.3.6). Ann. Math. (2) **179**.3 p. 1109-1120 (2014). [ZBL1297.14011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1297.14011).

---

P.S. If you want a more precise grip on numerical invariants of surfaces, there is a great tool by Pieter Belmans and Johan Commelin with loads and loads of data. See *Le superficie algebriche* at https://superficie.info.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I should probably post it as a separate question but would you also know examples of maximal Albanese dimension, please?

Comment: For your new question, form the blowing up at a point of an Abelian surface.

Comment: . . . Then blow up a point on the exceptional divisor.  All one-forms vanish at the intersection point of the exceptional divisors.

Comment: @JasonStarr very nice! I was thinking along similar lines to try to get the pullback on forms $\Omega^1_A \otimes \kappa(a(s)) \to \Omega^1_S \otimes \kappa(s)$ along the Albanese $a \colon S \to A$ to be the zero map, but I had some difficulty finding criteria for when a given generically finite map $S \to A$ is the Albanese map of $S$.